# Bake AO map from multires in Blender.2.82

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Back in 2.79 there was the ability (in blender render mode) to bake ao maps directly from multires. There was no need for a hp and lp mesh to do this. 
How can i achieve this in 2.82? The only available maps for baking from multires are the normal and displacement maps. 
In general what is the proper (and maybe the easiest) way to bake an ao map of a sculpted mesh with the multires modifier in blender 2.82?

BR,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest another approach.

1. In the Shader editor, using Cycles, add Emission shader, add Input -> Ambient Occlusion node and connect its AO output to Emission color input.
2. With viewport shading set to render tweak AO node's settings as you like.
3. In the Bake tab in Render Properties uncheck "Bake from Multires" checkbox and choose Emit as the Bake Type.

[image]

After that you can bake the result in a common way: create an image in Image Editor, choose it in Image texture in Shader editor, make sure the object is UV-unwrapped, active, and the Image Texture in the Shader editor is selected and press bake. As an emission shader is the only shader used, it bakes extremely fast.